# Strongholds seems to spawn under villages

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I've been doing some speedrunning in Minecraft Bedrock, and I have some certain clues on where strongholds could be after playing for a while.

*"If you get to the closest village 700+ blocks away from spawn, there's a chance that when you throw an eye, it will go directly under the village."*

Yep, it seems like Bedrock Edition's villages have a good chance of having a stronghold under it, and I have no ideas why this is so, as I am using a phone to play the game, and I don't know how to access the in-game code.

So is there some script on strongholds to naturally spawn under villages?

Comment: I would assume so because my friend and I agree that it’s almost impossible not to have a village above a stronghold, I don’t know how to get the code.

Comment: just more likely its fully possible for them to not, the same doesnt happen on java however

Comment: I think it might be worth if you dropped into [SalC1's discord](https://discord.com/invite/salc1) - it hosts the community focused on seed cracking and Minecraft world generation related exploits. Although they focus on Java Edition, it's possible to [convert](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-convert-minecraft-bedrock-seed-java-seed) BE seeds to JE seeds generating nearly the same world, so it might be within their area of interest (or they'd be willing to expand onto BE). What you claim is indeed an an interesting property and might be worth looking into, and they have the expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 1/10 chance that a stronghold will be under a village. Edit: to clarify: I do not know if this statistic is still accurate. I see no reason why it wouldn’t be still.

Comment: Where is the script? How can you be sure that it is a 1/10 chance?

Comment: There used to be a 1/10 chance,  and it never was changed in an update. It still for bedrock, so that’s how I know.

Comment: Clarifying the other post, a speedrun with the time 13 min 6 seconds held (or still holds) the world record. When analyzed, it was explained that there is a 1/10 chance for strongholds to spawn under villages. That’s how I know.

Comment: There is a 00.00001 chance of ***spawning*** in a village with the strong hold right underneath it