# Do strongholds spawn under abandoned villages?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Strongholds have a <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> chance to spawn under a village; does this also apply to abandoned villages? If so, does the reason for abandonment have any impact to this statistic?

Comment: try editing this to give a bit more detail

Comment: I would assume they mean the natural spawning abandon villages. These normally have cobwebs, mossy cobblestone (I have only seen them in plains....), and no villager (though sometimes some zombie villagers will spawn).

Comment: Can you supply the source of documentation stating there is a 10% chance for strongholds to generate under a village? [Your existing answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382177/274742) on another question also states this, but a comment states you learned the statistic from an explaination given while a world record speed run was being analyzed. Unfortunately, without the source of this information, we only *know*, without a doubt, that strongholds *sometimes* spawn under villages; but they're randomly generated throughout the world in BE which implies it's less than a 10% chance.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t believe so, I believe only under normal villages, as the Minecraft Wiki says [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold).

> In Bedrock Edition, strongholds generate randomly throughout the
> world. **They sometimes generate under a village.**

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Both these answers are incorrect.

Comment: The Minecraft wiki states that (paraphrased) on bedrock edition, there is no limit to how many strongholds generate in a world, and they have evwn been known to generate in the far lands.

Comment: Asp, I’ve seen YouTube cideos that show strongholds 8 million blocks out on bedrock edition.

Comment: @Deer492 I’m not denying that. I’m just saying they sometimes have a tendency to generate under villages.

Answer (score -1):

While its true that strongholds can generate under villages, I don't think it applies on abandoned ones. I have never seen a stronghold under one at all. You could try, though I doubt a stronghold would even generate under it.

You'll have a better chance that the stronghold would be under a village, but I'm not exactly sure if <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> is really the approximate chance for a stronghold to be under a village.

Comment: That might just be because abandoned villages are rarer than regular villages, so you’re less likely to see one around.

Answer (score -1):

I have, in fact, seen a lot if strongholds under abandoned villages.

The 1/10 chance applies to regular villages and abandoned villages.

Comment: Although you have seen this, do you have any reputable source that explicitly states this, such as the Minecraft Wiki?

Comment: I have seen it many times. Like, the major Bedrock speedrun seed back in 1.17 had the stronghold under an abandoned village. Why wouldn’t this be OK.

Comment: I’m just trying to give constructive criticism. Sources always help your answer become more trustworthy.

Comment: Actually, the game considers abandoned villages as villages (hence the /locate commans

Comment: command senses that if you type “/locate village” it will sometimes lead you to an abandoned village.

Comment: that’s pretty interesting. I never knew that.

Comment: Actually abandoned villages are a type of village, not a separate structure altogether.

Comment: Can you provide the seed and coords?